# How to navigate through multiple pages in one part of the bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am trying to implement a design to a flutter app. how do I implement a flutter app that stays on that section of the navbar without going to another page entirely and it stacks on the navigation stack on top of each other so when I press back it can go back. I would appreciate good feedback on this[image: Desired Image]

This is the code I have so far for the screen that holds the bottom navigation page and other screens

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iconly/iconly.dart';
import 'package:scree/Screens/DashboardScreens/analytics_screen.dart';

class BottomNavBarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBarScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 _BottomNavBarScreenState createState() => _BottomNavBarScreenState();
}

class _BottomNavBarScreenState extends State<BottomNavBarScreen> {
  final List _screens = [
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text('A'),
  ),
),
AnalyticsScreen(),
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text('C'),
  ),
),
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text('D'),
  ),
),
];
var currentIndex = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Scaffold(
  body: _screens[currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: size.width * .155,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [0, 1, 2, 3]
          .map(
            (index) => InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    currentIndex = index;
                  },
                );
              },
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: index == currentIndex ? 0 : size.width * .029,
                      right: size.width * .0422,
                      left: size.width * .0422,
                    ),
                    width: size.width * .128,
                    height: index == currentIndex ? 4 : 0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xff25307e),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    index == currentIndex
                        ? listOfIconsBold[index]
                        : listOfIconsLight[index],
                    size: size.width * .076,
                    color: index == currentIndex
                        ? Color(0xff25307e)
                        : Colors.black38,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    listOfText[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: index == currentIndex
                          ? Color(0xff25307e)
                          : Colors.black38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
}

List<IconData> listOfIconsLight = [
IconlyLight.category,
IconlyLight.chart,
IconlyLight.document,
IconlyLight.work
 ];
 List<IconData> listOfIconsBold = [
IconlyBold.category,
IconlyBold.chart,
IconlyBold.document,
IconlyBold.work
 ];

 List<String> listOfText = ['DashBoard', 'Analytics', 'My Products', 'Manage'];
}
```

Comment: You can do this using nested navigation. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the static Widget parameter that contain your button navigation bar and using this parameter for any page that you want.

I am not sure because I am using a package to create the bottom navigation bar and this widget can send the controller parameter that can be static type.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using normal bottom navigation bar , you could use cupertino bottom navigation bar.
In this the bottom navigation bar stays throughout the app

Also you can refer to this video
Try using first or last method in the video [Video](https://youtu.be/qj7jcuU2Z10)